# Need Help in Div Management Please

Tags: html, css

I am a Beginner Website Developer, I want to make my college's project but stuck at the beginning because my navigation div and small divs in navigation div are not going to transform or transit at once. when i apply transition at one of em with absolute position all (also apply absolute position to other three small divs) the all three of em except first disappears. Code is linked. I want to make navigation just like **IMDB's** Navigation. (with downside transition and with links and picture at one end.)

-Thank in advance.

HTML CODE:

```
<body>
<div id="Papadiv">

<header id="Header">

    <Div id="Logodiv">
    <img src="Images/Logo.jpg" height="100px" width="100px" />
    </Div>
<Div id="Titlediv">
<font size="+5" face="Comic Sans MS, cursive">MobilePassion.com</font> 

</Div>
</header>



<nav id="Nav1">
    <div id="navoption1">
    <a href="Index.html">
    New Arrivals</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navoption2">
    <a href="Famousmodels.html">
    Famous Models</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navoption3">
    <a href="Whoweare.html">
    Who We Are?</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navoption4">
    <a href="Contactus.html">
    Contact Us</a>
    </div>

</nav>



/* CSS Document */



#Nav1
{
background-color: #FDAA2F;
height:50px;
width:800px;

}

#navoption1
{
background-color:#FD771E;
height:10px;
width:160px;
border-radius:20px;
float: left;
color:#722703;
padding:20px;
text-align:center;



}


#navoption2
{
background-color:#FD771E;
height:10px;
width:160px;
border-radius:20px;
float: left;
color:#722703;
padding:20px;
text-align:center;



}


#navoption3
{
background-color:#FD771E;
height:10px;
width:160px;
border-radius:20px;
float: left;
color:#722703;
padding:20px;
text-align:center;

}


#navoption4
{
background-color:#FD771E;
height:10px;
width:160px;
border-radius:20px;
float: left;
color:#722703;
padding:20px;
text-align:center;





#navoption1:hover
{
color:#C13D04;
background-color: #F5530E;

animation:alternate;
text-decoration:blink;
background-image:url(Rose%20(1).jpg)
}

#navoption2:hover
{
color:#C13D04;
background-color: #F5530E;

animation:alternate;
text-decoration:blink
}
#navoption3:hover
{
color:#C13D04;
background-color: #F5530E;

animation:alternate;
text-decoration:blink
}
#navoption4:hover
{
color:#C13D04;
background-color: #F5530E;

animation:alternate;
text-decoration:blink
}
```

Comment: Where is your HTML markup? Is really the whole stylesheet required to solve the problem? And please try to phrase a real question. You just describe a big task.

Comment: Dear real problem is i need to make navigation like IMDB's Navigation with a drop down menu in detail without using any scripts or jquary. (just HTML and CSS) Hope u understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think first off you need to do some research on how to build a "CSS Mega Drop Down Menu". (That's usually what they are called and you should be able to find a good example in which you can structure your styling off of.)

A "classic" drop down menu usually contains lists nested (or in your case - divs) within parent list items.

"[Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu--net-15129)" is a good step by step example that I think should get you off and running.

Comment: Thnx Tulon. I am sure this is going yo help me.

Comment: If this is the answer, please "accept it" as the correct answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have been rtying to find a good resource for an example. These are good examples to learn from i think. http://code-tricks.com/simple-css-drop-down-menu/ , http://css-tricks.com/simple-jquery-dropdowns/ . It would also be wise for user experience to use hoverintent (http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) or a delay. This creates a better user experience.